# how to use conda accelerate / benchmarks?

Tags: numpy, conda, hpc, intel-mkl

I'm attempting to use Conda Accelerate to speedup some data preprocessing, but initial benchmarks indicate either I'm not using it correctly or it has no effect on FFT & linear algebra execution times in numpy and librosa. Re-reading the literature - does this mean I'm supposed to decorate and recode every ndarray operation as in the [batch-matmul example](https://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/quickstart) for NumbaPro? I'd assumed I simply installed and it made numpy faster, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Benchmarks and code are below. I've installed accelerate via `conda install accelerate` and also imported it for good measure.

Thanks!

Result - negligible difference before and after `conda install accelerate`

```
Total time was 25.356
Total load time was 1.6743
Total math time was 22.1599
Total save time was 1.5139
Total stft math time was 12.9219
Total other numpy math time was 9.1886
```

Relevant code:

```
loads, maths, saves = [], [], []
stfts, nps = [], []
# now we have a dict of all source files grouped by voice                                         
for i in range(30):
    v0_fn = v0_list[i]
    v1_fn = v1_list[i]
    tl0 = time.time()
    # Process v0 & v1 file                                                                        
    v0_fn = signal_dir+v0_fn
    v0, fs_s =  librosa.load(v0_fn, sr=None)
    v1_fn = signal_dir+v1_fn
    v1, fs_s =  librosa.load(v1_fn, sr=None)
    tl1 = time.time()
    loads.append((tl1-tl0))
    mix = v0 + v1
    # Capture the magnitude and phase of signal and signal + noise                                
    tm0 = time.time()
    v0_stft = librosa.stft(v0, int(frame_size*fs), int(step_size*fs)).transpose()
    tm1 = time.time()
    v0_mag = (v0_stft.real**2 + v0_stft.imag**2)**0.5
    v0_pha = np.arctan2(v0_stft.imag, v0_stft.real)
    v0_rtheta = np.stack((v0_mag, v0_pha), axis=0)
    tm2 = time.time()
    v1_stft = librosa.stft(v1, int(frame_size*fs), int(step_size*fs)).transpose()
    tm3 = time.time()
    v1_mag = (v1_stft.real**2 + v1_stft.imag**2)**0.5
    v1_pha = np.arctan2(v1_stft.imag, v1_stft.real)
    v1_rtheta = np.stack((v1_mag, v1_pha), axis=0)
    tm4 = time.time()
    mix_stft = librosa.stft(mix, int(frame_size*fs), int(step_size*fs)).transpose()
    tm5 = time.time()
    mix_mag = (mix_stft.real**2 + mix_stft.imag**2)**0.5
    mix_pha = np.arctan2(mix_stft.imag, mix_stft.real)
    mix_rtheta = np.stack((mix_mag, mix_pha), axis=0)
    tm6 = time.time()   
    stfts += [tm1-tm0, tm3-tm2, tm5-tm4]
    nps += [tm2-tm1, tm4-tm3, tm6-tm5]                            
    data['sig_rtheta'] = v0_rtheta
    data['noi_rtheta'] = v1_rtheta
    data['mix_rtheta'] = mix_rtheta
    tl2 = time.time()
    maths.append(tl2-tl1)
    with open(write_name, 'w') as f:
        cPickle.dump(all_info, f, protocol=-1)
    tl3 = time.time()
    saves.append(tl3-tl2)

t1 = time.time()
print 'Total time was %.3f' % (t1-t0)
print 'Total load time was %.4f' % np.sum(loads)
print 'Total math time was %.4f' % np.sum(maths)
print 'Total save time was %.4f' % np.sum(saves)
print 'Total stft math was %.4f' % np.sum(stfts)
print 'Total other numpy math time was %.4f' % np.sum(nps)
```

Comment: Can this acceleration method speed up code imported from other modules, or can it only work on the barebones Python and numpy that you  wrote yourself?  Imported functions, especially if they call compiled code, are more than likely a 'black box' that the acceleration can't touch.

Comment: Great point, and I'm suspicious you're correct regarding Accelerate's access to librosa. That said, it doesn't seem to be accelerating the accessible Numpy operations either :P